# Degenerate plane conics form closed subset in $\mathbb{P}^5$ isomorphic to projection of $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-varieties

I am doing the following problem (Exercise 5.3.5) from "An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry" by Karen E. Smith et al.:

> Show that the subset of all degenerate plane conics naturally form a closed subset in $\mathbb{P}^5$ of dimension four, isomorphic to the projection, from $\mathbb{P}^8$, of the Segre four-fold $\Sigma_{22}$, where $\Sigma_{22}$ denotes the image of $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2$ under the Segre map.

I can see that degenerate conics at least can be embedded as a subset in $\mathbb{P}^5$, since any conic has the form
$$aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2+dXY+eXZ+fYZ=0$$
in $\mathbb{P}^2$, which can be associated with the point $[a:b:c:d:e:f]\in\mathbb{P}^5$. But I have no idea how $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2$ is related here.

Is there some geometric explanation? I know determinants can be used to determine whether a conic is degenerate but I don't think that is very "natural" in the context of this problem.

Comment: Hint: think about exactly what a degenerate plane conic is - what makes it degenerate? (Something happens that normally doesn't - what?)

Comment: @KReiser hmm, all I can think of is that a degenerate plane conic is in the form of either lines or points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A degenerate conic is given by an equation that factors: that is, the conic $V(ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dxz+eyz+fz^2)$ is degenerate iff $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dxz+eyz+fz^2 = (px+qy+rz)(sx+ty+uz).$$ Now, just as you identified the six coefficients of the equation of the conic with points in $\Bbb P^5$, you can identify the coefficients on each of the linear equations with points in $\Bbb P^2$. Expanding the product $$(px+qy+rz)(sx+ty+uz) = (ps)x^2+(pt+qs)xy+(qt)y^2+(pu+rs)xz+(qu+rt)yz+(ru)z^2$$ we see that all the entries on the right hand side are sums of products of one coordinate from the first entry and one coordinate from the second entry. As these products are exactly the coordinates on the Segre embedding and we can take sums of coordinates through a linear projection, we have the result. (I'd recommend working through an example to see how this projection works for yourself - try projection from $[0:-1:1]$ to $V(x_2)$ in $\Bbb P^2$ and note that a point $[a:b:c]$ goes to $[a:b+c:0]$).